# Basic Java: WOD with GUI (needing pauses/stops)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

All.

Trying to make a game similar to Oregon Trail with Java Swing. So far I have the following happen when you click a button:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String name = jTextField1.getText();
jTextField1.setText("");
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
jTextArea1.setText("Oh, that's right! " + name+ " is your name." + newline + 
        "Welcome to Santa's team, "+name+"!"+ newline +
        "I hope you're still planning on making it"+newline+"to the North Pole by December 25th..." 
        +newline+ "Wait, who is that teddy bear with you?"
        );

String name2 = jTextField1.getText();
jTextField1.setText("");
jTextArea1.setText(name2+ " the teddy bear? I like it." + newline +
        "Let me work some magic..."
        );
}
```

However, as I'm sure you have realized...this runs straight through to the end when you click the button the first time. I've looked at listeners, pauses, etc... but I'm not sure what the best/easiest route is. I'm really just making this as a fun little game for my wife and I want it to be a javaTestArea that reads things out, a javaTextField for her to enter strings or choices (1,2,3, etc...) and a submit button.

I do appreciate the help; Thank you.

Comment: Oregon trail? Didn't it have a lot more dysentery and a lot less teddy bears?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is written using the linear logic of a console program, and so I'm guessing that you in fact have lifted this code from a console program that you've previously written. The problem though is that Swing applications, like most GUI applications don't run in a linear fashion, but that instead they are **event-driven**, and so you will have to completely re-think your program logic so that it will respond well in an event-driven environment.

You will likely want to create classes for the entities involved in your program, then have them change "state" (often this means changing the values held by fields in objects of this class) as the program runs, and then base the program's responses based on the state of these fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are combining what should be two separate button click listeners into one. You prompt for the teddy bear's name so let the user enter the text and when they click the ok button have a different on click listener do the second part.